# Trace messages on StackExchange Redis client

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

We are using this [StackExhange Redis C# client](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/Docs/Basics.md) and occasionally experiencing errors such as this:

> StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException: No connection is
>   available to service this operation: EXISTS
>   OnDemand:ExportDocument:Subscription:f3d45517-c26e-4e99-82c0-5c532a68081b
>   at
>   StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ExecuteSyncImpl[T](Message
>   message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server) in
>   c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\3ae0647004edff78\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange\Redis\ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line
>   1734

Looking through the code, it appears as though we can enable some sort of verbose tracing to gain an additional understanding of what is happening underneath the hood. I  looked through the configuration part of the document and there is no mention of tracing there.

Any one with ideas on how to enable tracing on this client?

Comment: Do have a retry policy in your code? Take a look a the [Issues](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/search?q=No+connection+is+available+to+service+this+operation&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93) mentioning this error

Comment: Does not look like it. Guess will start there.

Answer (score 6):

`ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect()` optionally accepts a `TextWriter` for logging.